# Java read Json array in Json object

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a String like this:

```
{"api_authentication":{"api_response":{"token":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","firstname":"John","disabled":false,"attempts":0,"id":123,"lastname":"Malkovitch","expire":false,"status":0}}}
```

I can turn this string into an object:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
```

But I don't find how to get the token value, I tried creating JSONArrays but i get a not found exception.

Comment: the posted code seems OK... you should post what you tried, better, a [mcve] else you risk the question being closed (unanswered)

Comment: @carlos Heuberger, he says he tried creating JSONArrays, but don't you think that is why he's not able to access it? Because what's posted in the question seems to be more like a single JSON Object rather than an array of JSON's. Just that I'm not really very familiar with JSON's in java. So am making a query with you.

Comment: There's no array in that json object. I think you should re-phrase the question. Assuming you're using `org.json` as a library all you need to do is to get the children objects until you get to the value:

`jobj.getJSONObject("api_authentication").getJSONObject("api_response").getString("token")`

If you'd like a better DSL I'd suggest looking into https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath :)

Comment: Please look at the documentation (2nd Google result for JSONObject): https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html
You can use e.g. `getJsonObject("api_authentication")`

Comment: Have you tried String token = jobj.getJSONObject("api_authentication").getJSONObject("api_response").getString("token");

Comment: @Rai I cannot see **how** he tried to do it.... actually I do not know which framework he is using.

Comment: @carlos Heuberger, no offence meant buddy. I was just asking a few doubts, cuz I myself am a newbie to handling JSON's in java. As you were the only one who had responded to the question, I had to ask you. It was a sincere doubt and not meant to oppose what you had told.

Comment: @Rai I have only commented, not responded, since I am newbie with JSON and it is not meant as an answer is more like trying to  help getting help (one of the reasons to close a question is missing of MCVE)... [:-)

Comment: Peace buddy. Hope you haven't taken any offence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this ;

```
final JSONObject api_authentication = jobj.getJSONObject("api_authentication");
final JSONObject api_response = api_authentication.getJSONObject("api_response");
System.out.println(api_response.getString("token"));
```

if `JSON` any value in curlybrackets `{ ... }` , this is `jsonObject` . If values are in `[ ... ]`, this is `JsonArray`. Also you can get which one is object or array, and get it relevant fields from this. So all of json elements are with curly bracket in your problem. Get it as `JsonObject`.

Comment: Remember to check if the key exists before getting the object `jobj.containsKey("api_authentication")`

Comment: Of course , this getJsonObject throws JsonException. He have to provide this with try catch block. I posted only how to get token from related json

Comment: Understood it like that; just for newbies that might read this thread ;-)

Answer (score 1):

this might work by the look of what you have posted. The posted code snippet shows that it is a single JSON object and not a JSONArray. 
Hence try the following:

```
JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(response);
String newtoken = jobj.getJSONObject("api_authentication").getJSONObject("api_response").getString("token"); //declare the variable `newtoken` somhwere before of a desired type
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
Object tokenValue =  jobj.getJSONObject("api_authentication").getJSONObject("api_response").get("token");
```

After that you can cast the object to the desired type or use something like `getString(.)` straightaway.

Comment: it should be getJsonObject, there's no Array in his example.